# Why is the upper half not aligned with the lower half of the card

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a card element in my HTML DOM. This card is cut in two halves. Those halves are supposed to align "seamlessly" So no white line in the middle, no borders missaligned.

This is what I tried: For whatever reason the elements borders do not align...
Is it simply due to the lines not being very large, thus the (what I think to be) anti-aliasing does this? Especially since it only happens to some of the cards and resizing moves the problem to another card. If this is the case do I have any other option than making the cards bigger? Because doing so would mean that I fit less on the screen, something I don't want to happen.

```js
// Suits and values for the cards
const suits = ['♤', '♡', '♧', '♢']
const cardRanks = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'C', 'Q', 'K']


function createCard(suit, rank) {
    let card = document.createElement('card')
    
    card.setAttribute('suit', suit)
    card.setAttribute('rank', rank)

    for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        let cardHalf = document.createElement('card-half')

        cardHalf.className = `half-${i}`
        cardHalf.innerHTML = rank

        if (suit === 'T') {
            cardHalf.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://placehold.jp/150x150.png')"
        }

        card.appendChild(cardHalf)
    }

    return card
}

// Create the cards
// First trumps
const deck = []
for (let i = 1; i <= 21; i++) {
    deck.push(createCard('T', i))
}
// Add the excuse
deck.push(createCard('T', 'EX'))

// Add all the cards from the other suits
suits.forEach(suit => {
    cardRanks.forEach(rank => {
        deck.push(createCard(suit, rank))
    })
})

const deckElement = document.querySelector('.deck')
deck.forEach(card => {deckElement.appendChild(card)})
```

```css
:root {
    --card-size-unit: calc(100vw/75);
    --white: #fff;
    --black: #000;
    --red: #f00;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(14, 68, 4);
    margin: 0;
}

.deck {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

card {
    margin: .25em;

    border-radius: calc(.3 * var(--card-size-unit));
    border: calc(.2 * var(--card-size-unit)) solid var(--white);
    background-color: var(--white);
    
    --card-color: var(--black);
}

card[suit="♢"], card[suit="♡"] {
    --card-color: var(--red);
}

card-half {
    font-size: calc(1.5 * var(--card-size-unit));
    color: var(--card-color);

    display: block;
    width: calc(5.3 * var(--card-size-unit));
    height: calc(.5 * 10.7 * var(--card-size-unit));

    background-position-y: bottom;
    background-size: 100% calc(calc(.5 * 10.7 * var(--card-size-unit)) - calc(2 * var(--card-size-unit)));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    border: calc(.1 * var(--card-size-unit)) solid var(--black);
    border-bottom: 0 solid var(--white);
    border-radius: calc(.3 * var(--card-size-unit)) calc(.3 * var(--card-size-unit)) 0 0;
}

card[suit="T"] card-half {
    text-align: center;
}

card:not([suit="T"]) {
    text-indent: 3px;
}

card-half.half-1 {
    transform: scale(-1, -1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cardStyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="genCards.js" defer></script>
    <title>Card test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Suit five options: normal suits or trump -->
    <!-- Value: for normal suits, 1 through 10 and J, C, Q, K, for trumps 1 through 21 and Excuse -->
    <div class="deck" id="deck"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I noticed happening is it aligning perfectly when the screen width is 1260px